# Android ListView Activity Throws a NullPointerException when restarting after a prolonged period of time

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, android-lifecycle, android-logcat

### Problem

I'm making a simple app that retrieves a data set from a webserver in JSON form, parses it into objects contained in an ArrayList. This array list is then output in the form of a list view. It work's beautifully to start with. Then when I leave the app for a while and come back to it, I get a ANR and have to Force close. However simply leaving the app and returning to it is completely fine. (See full LogCat below) I have included all the relevant code (with my webserver url removed) below. Any help in solving this matter would be appreciated.

I assume it has something to do with the app resuming `onResume()` or maybe `onRestart()` so I tried overriding both those methods with some `isEmpty()` and `!null` checks to no avail.

**TL;DR:** App not responding due to NullPointerException, likely because of some Lifecycle event but can't figure out why.

Another possible mess is my attempt at a singleton class. (Never really used static based instances references before)

### LogCat Output of App failing to restart

This LogCat is a read out of the app failing after going to the home screen, opening many other apps, then returning to my app. This does not happen after simply leaving and returning to the app.

```
05-14 17:21:45.140: W/dalvikvm(22985): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4103a2a0)
05-14 17:21:45.150: E/AndroidRuntime(22985): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-14 17:21:45.150: E/AndroidRuntime(22985): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.liamjpeters.retrievedata/com.liamjpeters.activities.ListActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-14 17:21:45.150: E/AndroidRuntime(22985):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2100)
05-14 17:21:45.150: E/AndroidRuntime(22985):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
05-14 17:21:45.150: E/AndroidRuntime(22985):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
05-14 17:21:45.150: E/AndroidRuntime(22985):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
05-14 17:21:45.150: E/AndroidRuntime(22985):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-14 17:21:45.150: E/AndroidRuntime(22985):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-14 17:21:45.150: E/AndroidRuntime(22985):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
05-14 17:21:45.150: E/AndroidRuntime(22985):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-14 17:21:45.150: E/AndroidRuntime(22985):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-14 17:21:45.150: E/AndroidRuntime(22985):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
05-14 17:21:45.150: E/AndroidRuntime(22985):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
05-14 17:21:45.150: E/AndroidRuntime(22985):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-14 17:21:45.150: E/AndroidRuntime(22985): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-14 17:21:45.150: E/AndroidRuntime(22985):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getCount(ArrayAdapter.java:330)
05-14 17:21:45.150: E/AndroidRuntime(22985):    at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:466)
05-14 17:21:45.150: E/AndroidRuntime(22985):    at com.liamjpeters.activities.ListActivity.onCreate(ListActivity.java:48)
05-14 17:21:45.150: E/AndroidRuntime(22985):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
05-14 17:21:45.150: E/AndroidRuntime(22985):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1083)
05-14 17:21:45.150: E/AndroidRuntime(22985):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)
05-14 17:21:45.150: E/AndroidRuntime(22985):    ... 11 more
```

### Main Activity

***The gist of the code (What it's meant to do):*** Just your bog standard main activity. Has a button that when pressed executes an Async Task that retrieves data from a webserver. When it's finished it launches the `ListActivity` activity. Importantly here is where my Singletons instance is set

```
package com.liamjpeters.activities;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

import com.liamjpeters.content.Ticket;
import com.liamjpeters.content.Tickets;
import com.liamjpeters.getData.GetTickets;
import com.liamjpeters.retrievedata.R;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button btn;
    ProgressBar pb;
    ArrayList<Ticket> tickets = new ArrayList<Ticket>();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnConnect);
        pb = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pbconnect);
        pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getServerData();
                pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    private void getServerData(){
        GetTickets gsd = new GetTickets(this);
        gsd.execute();
    }

    public void gotServerData(ArrayList<Ticket> tickets){
        pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        this.tickets = tickets;
        Tickets.setInstance(tickets);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ListActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent); 
    }

}
```

### GetTickets.java

***The gist of the code (What it's meant to do):*** Gets the data from the server and parses it into objects in an ArrayList called *tickets*. This works like a charm.

```
package com.liamjpeters.getData;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

import com.liamjpeters.activities.MainActivity;
import com.liamjpeters.content.Ticket;

public class GetTickets extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    MainActivity mAct;
    ArrayList<Ticket> tickets = new ArrayList<Ticket>();

    public GetTickets(Activity activ){
        mAct = (MainActivity) activ;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        mAct.gotServerData(tickets);
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        InputStream is = null;
        String result = "";
        // Connect to the server and obtain the data from the Server via the PHP Script.
        // This script returns the MYSQL results encoded in JSON format
        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("REMOVED BUT WORKS, TRUST ME");
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
        }

        // Converts the returned HTTPEntity into a string that can be parsed
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // Parses the JSON data
        try {
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            result = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                tickets.add(new Ticket(json_data.getInt("ticket_id"),json_data.getString("ticket_name"),json_data.getString("ticket_location"), json_data.getString("ticket_problem_area"),json_data.getString("ticket_description"),json_data.getInt("ticket_priority"),json_data.getInt("ticket_time")));
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

### Ticket.java

***The gist of the code (What it's meant to do):*** Just a data object with some convenience methods.

```
package com.liamjpeters.content;

public class Ticket {

    private String name;
    private String location;
    private String problemArea;
    private String description;
    private int priority;
    private int timeInt;
    private int id;
    private String timeString;
    private boolean isNew = false;;

    public Ticket(int id,String name, String location, String problemArea, String description, int priority, int time){
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.location = location;
        this.problemArea = problemArea;
        this.description = description;
        this.priority = priority;
        this.timeInt = time;
        if (((System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L)-time) <84600){
            isNew = true;
        }
        timeString = new java.util.Date((long) time * 1000).toString();
    }

    public Ticket clone(){
        return new Ticket(Integer.valueOf(id), new String(name), new String(location), new String(problemArea), new String(description), Integer.valueOf(priority), Integer.valueOf(timeInt));
    }

    public int getID(){
        return id;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
    public String getLocation(){
        return location;
    }
    public String getProblemArea(){
        return problemArea;
    }
    public String getDescription(){
        return description;
    }
    public int getPriority(){
        return priority;
    }
    public int getTimeInt(){
        return timeInt;
    }

    public String getTimeString(){
        return timeString;
    }

    public Boolean getIsNew(){
        return isNew;
    }
}
```

### ListActivity.java

***The gist of the code (What it's meant to do):*** The activity that displays a list view using my custom list item. Likely the lifecycles of this activity that are my problem

```
package com.liamjpeters.activities;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.liamjpeters.content.Ticket;
import com.liamjpeters.content.TicketListAdapter;
import com.liamjpeters.content.Tickets;
import com.liamjpeters.retrievedata.R;

public class ListActivity extends Activity {

    ListView lstTest;
    TicketListAdapter listAdapter;
    ArrayList<Ticket> tickets;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        tickets = Tickets.getInstance();
            //Ony of my attempts at a fix :S
        if (tickets == null || tickets.isEmpty()){
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent); 
        }
        setContentView(R.layout.listlayout);
        lstTest = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lstText);
        listAdapter = new TicketListAdapter(ListActivity.this,R.layout.listitemrel , tickets);
        lstTest.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

### Tickets.java

Kind of a singleton class that helps pass my ArrayList between activities. It originally just stored a reference that it received. I then had a notion that the original ArrayList was created on a thread that must have been disposed of at some point hence the reference would become null. This did not fix the problem

```
package com.liamjpeters.content;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Tickets {

private static ArrayList<Ticket> instance;

    public static void setInstance(ArrayList<Ticket> instance){
        Tickets.instance = new ArrayList<Ticket>(instance.size());
        for (int i = 0; i<instance.size(); i++){
            Tickets.instance.add(instance.get(i).clone());
        }
    }

    public static ArrayList<Ticket> getInstance(){
        return instance;
    }

}
```

### TicketListAdapter

Bog Standard ArrayAdapter. A million examples of these online

```
package com.liamjpeters.content;

import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.liamjpeters.retrievedata.R;

public class TicketListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Ticket> {

    int textViewResourceId;

    public TicketListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<Ticket> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        this.textViewResourceId = textViewResourceId;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //The linear layout that the listview is contained within
        LinearLayout ticketView;

        //Get the current ticket object
        Ticket ticket = getItem(position);

        //Inflate the view
        if(convertView==null){
            ticketView = new LinearLayout(getContext());
            String inflater = Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE;
            LayoutInflater vi;
            vi = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(inflater);
            vi.inflate(textViewResourceId, ticketView, true);
        }else{
            ticketView = (LinearLayout) convertView;
        }
        //Get the text boxes from the list item XML file
        TextView isNew = (TextView)ticketView.findViewById(R.id.tvIsNew);
        TextView idText =(TextView)ticketView.findViewById(R.id.tvTicketID);
        TextView nameText =(TextView)ticketView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
        TextView locationText =(TextView)ticketView.findViewById(R.id.tvLocation);
        TextView problemText =(TextView)ticketView.findViewById(R.id.tvProblem);
        TextView dateText =(TextView)ticketView.findViewById(R.id.tvDate);
        ImageView priorityImage = (ImageView)ticketView.findViewById(R.id.ivPriority);

        //Assign the appropriate data from our alert object above
        if (ticket.getIsNew()){
            isNew.setText("NEW!");
        }
        idText.setText(""+ticket.getID());
        nameText.setText("Who: " + ticket.getName());
        locationText.setText("Where: "+ ticket.getLocation());
        problemText.setText("What: "+ticket.getProblemArea());
        dateText.setText(ticket.getTimeString());

        switch (ticket.getPriority()){
        case 0:
            priorityImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.low);
            break;
        case 1:
            priorityImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.med);
            break;
        case 2:
            priorityImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.high);
            break;
        default:
            priorityImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.low);
            break;
        }
        return ticketView;  
    }
}
```

So there you have. Any help, big or small is appreciated. See some code that could be done better then please let me know. I'm looking to not only solve my problem but learn as much as possible.

Thanks :)

Comment: What is at line 48 of `ListActivity`?

Comment: Nothing. Only goes up to 42!

Comment: Next time you really should try to determine which parts of the code are relevant to your problem and post those. We can always ask to see more bits, but it is daunting to have to scroll through all that code. Not a lot of people have the stamina to do that. Anyway, just a suggestion (it will increase your chances of getting help in the future).

Comment: Thanks David, I'll bear that in mind in future!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source of the problem is that after some time, the Android framework kills off your application process. When it restarts it, all your static data (including the singleton `Tickets` object) are set to default values. You need to detect this situation and reinitialize things to the state you need to function.

One consequence of this is that in your `ListActivity`, when you discover that `Tickets.getInstance()` returns `null`, you should call `finish()`<sup>*</sup> after starting `MainActivity`. Otherwise it continues with trying to initialize the list activity.

<sup>*</sup> and immediately return, as David Wasser points out in his comment.

Comment: Not only that, but you need to `return` after calling `finish()` so that you don't execute the rest of your `onCreate()`.

Comment: I have no idea how I forgot to `finish()` the activity. Android 101 **Facepalm**. Thanks for both reading all of that and the answer. Any idea how to persist `Tickets` longer without SQLite DB? Or better still, how to pass an ArrayList of Objects from one Activity to another?

Comment: You can pass data around as extras in an `Intent`, but if there is a lot of data this is pretty inefficient/messy. You can also just serialize the data to a file in the application's private data area if that is easier for you than putting it in a DB.

Comment: @DavidWasser @TedHopp Why would you suggest calling `finish()` in such situation? Just because application was killed doesn't mean user should be put in unexpected situation. Application should show what was there when they switched to other tasks when user returns. That may be after few hours, but also after few minutes in some conditions.

Comment: @MaciejGórski it all depends on the situation. All apps aren't alike. If it isn't a big deal to redirect the user to the root activity and start again, then just do that. If the user went away from the app you don't always need to restore everything. I would examine this on a case-by-case basis. If saving the current situation is difficult or complicated, sometimes it just isn't worth the trouble. A lot of time it depends on who is paying your salary ;-)

Comment: @DavidWasser Sure. We all do it like that, but in this specific case suggesting this seems like a bad idea. The data is from server and should be retrieved only once and stored in DB (+ updated on regular basis if it changes).

Comment: @LiamJPeters - You can save and restore the ticket data by overriding `onSaveInstanceState()`. You'll probably have to tweak the `Ticket` class so you can serialize the `Tickets` array. See [Recreating an Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html) for more info.

Comment: @DavidWasser - Good point about returning after calling `finish()`!

Answer (score 1):

`tickets = Tickets.getInstance();` is your offender.

You should not store data in singletons / static variables. They are wiped when the process is killed. Make sure you persist data and read it when it is not available in memory. Also use `onSaveInstanceState` and / or send data via `Intent` when starting `Activity`.

Comment: There is nothing inherently wrong in storing data in singletons. You just need to understand that Android may kill your process if it is idle for a long time and you need to recognize that that has happened and then recover appropriately (either reload your singletons, or redirect to the root activity of your application as necessary).

Comment: Also I can see no way of passing an ArrayList<object> through an intent. Unless I'm hugely mistaken

Comment: @LiamJPeters um, how about `Intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra()`? You just need to make sure that your `object` implements `Parcelable`

Comment: @DavidWasser `"There is nothing inherently wrong in storing data in singletons."` Of course. I meant storing **only** in the static var, but not persisting and / or keeping it in *magical* system server process.

Comment: @DavidWasser I take it that this creates a new arraylist when it's passed in then and doesn't do it referentially?

Comment: @LiamJPeters When using `Intent.put...` methods you are making sure your data is not lost when your process is killed. When the process is restored, you can retrieve the list in `onCreate` of your `ListActivity`.

Comment: @MaciejGórski Thanks. I have implemented the Parcelable ArrayList solution and it works a treat